# CakePHP 3.x - Testing actions that require Authentication

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to run unit tests in CakePHP 3.0, but all actions require authentication.

I tried to set session data with `$this->session()` like in the [official documentation here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-actions-that-require-authentication), but phpunit always returns error when I test responsecode with `$this->assertResponseOk()` :

> Status code is not between 200 and 204
>
> Failed asserting that 302 is equal to 204 or is less than 204.

Here is my simple test :

```
<?php
namespace ContactManager\Test\TestCase\Controller;
use Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase;
use ContactManager\Controller\ContactsController;

/**
 * ContactManager\Controller\ContactsController Test Case
 */
class ContactsControllerTest extends IntegrationTestCase {

    public function setUserSession() {
        $auth = [
            'Auth' => [
                'User' => [
                    'id' => 2,
                    'email' => 'john.doe@crm.com',
                    'firstname' => 'John',
                    'lastname' => 'Doe',
                    'gender' => 'm',
                    'birthday' => '1975-08-01',
                    'state' => 1,
                    'created' => '2015-04-01 22:26:51',
                    'modified' => '2015-04-01 22:26:51'
                ]
            ]
        ];
        return $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Test index action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testIndex() {
        $this->session($this->setUserSession());
        $this->get('/contacts/index');
        $this->assertResponseOk(); 
    }

}
```

My AppController loads AuthComponent and uses `beforeFilter()` to configure the autorize method :

```
public function initialize() {
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', ['authorize' => 'Controller',
        'loginAction' => [
            'prefix' => false,
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'prefix' => 'admin',
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'dashboard'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'prefix' => false,
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ],
                'scope' => [
                    'Users.state' => 1
                ]
            ]
    ]]);
}

public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\Event $event) {
    $this->Auth->authorize = 'Controller';
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
}
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Find out why it redirects. But the session itself should work to "make it think" this user is logged in. Also I would use the array syntax for URLs, this way you can be sure the Routing is what you expect. The URL as string can be tested in a separate test case.

Comment: Thanks @mark, you're right. 

The problem didn't come from the "fake" session data. The `isAuthorized()` method, that always returns `false`, forced the redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User session data work well.

The problem was inside my `isAuthorized()` method, that always returned `false` and forced redirection.

Comment: How do you fix the `isAuthorized()` to not always return `false`?